# To have external scope for variables in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, scope

I am simply trying to store $username in a file that will be included in all the pages after a user logins.Thus, this $username will change dynamically according to the user that has logged in.

**includeusername.php**

```php
<?php

     $username=$_POST['username'];

    echo $username;
?>
```

The variable does get initialized in includeusername.php ,as echo gives the value.On including this file in the main page which will display  "Welcome $username!" i write this code

```
     Welcome  <?php  echo  $username;  ?>!
```

The error shown is Undefined index: username.
How to have access to data from other page?And transfer it to the next page too!
I've used the following but it didn't work:

- sessionStorage()
- $_SESSION['username']
- include/require

Any other idea to have persistent data across the web pages?

Comment: have u started the session and assigned the value to session username

Comment: session_start(); and then $_SESSION["username"] = $username; in one page and the other page has print_r($_SESSION).Doesn't work!

Comment: Can you provide more code? Maybe you forgot call session_start(); before trying to get $username from $_SESSION['username'].

Comment: try changing to `$_GET['username']`

Comment: Oh yes ...session_start();  was not included...it's working now...Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["username"]=$_REQUEST['username'];
?>
```

In your includeusername.php use

```
Welcome  <?php  echo  $_SESSION["username"];  ?>!
```

Answer (score 0):

start the see [SESSION START](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

```
<?php
   session_start();
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    echo $username;
   echo "Assigning session value to: " . $username;
   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

?>
```